# Recursive and iterative implementation on Kosaraju algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

[Kosaraju algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) is mainly phrased as two *recursive* subroutines running *postorder* [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) twice to mark [SCCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) with linear time complexity *O(V+E)* below,

> 1. For each vertex \$u\$ of the graph, mark \$u\$ as unvisited. Let \$L\$ be empty.
> 2. For each vertex \$u\$ of the graph do Visit(\$u\$), where Visit(\$u\$) is the recursive subroutine:
>        If \$u\$ is unvisited then:
>            1. Mark \$u\$ as visited.
>            2. For each out-neighbour \$v\$ of \$u\$, do Visit(\$v\$).
>            3. Prepend \$u\$ to \$L\$.
>        Otherwise do nothing.
> 3. For each element \$u\$ of \$L\$ in order, do Assign(\$u\$,\$u\$) where Assign(\$u\$,\$root\$) is the recursive subroutine:
>        If \$u\$ has not been assigned to a component then:
>            1. Assign \$u\$ as belonging to the component whose root is \$root\$.
>            2. For each in-neighbour \$v\$ of \$u\$, do Assign(\$v\$,\$root\$).
>        Otherwise do nothing.

Here is the *recursive* implementation in *Python* according to the above recipe,

```
def kosaraju(G):
    
    # postorder DFS on G to transpose the graph and push root vertices to L
    
    N = len(G)
    T, L, U = [[] for _ in range(N)], [], [False] * N
    
    def visit(u):
        if not U[u]:
            U[u] = True
            for v in G[u]:
                visit(v)
                T[v].append(u)
            L.append(u)
    
    for u in range(N):
        visit(u)
    
    # postorder DFS on T to pop root vertices from L and mark SCCs
    
    C = [None] * N
    
    def assign(u, r):
        if U[u]:
            U[u] = False
            C[u] = r
            for v in T[u]:
                assign(v, r)
    
    while L:
        u = L.pop()
        assign(u, u)
    
    return C
```

The following *iterative* implementation scales well against the stack overflow due to excessively deep recursion.
I revised the inner loop of the first *iterative* DFS so the linear time complexity *O(V+E)* is guaranteed now,
however it deserves to be shared for further improvement.
I'll be glad about all your opinions or alternative implementations.

```
def kosaraju(G):
    
    # postorder DFS on G to transpose the graph and push root vertices to L
    N = len(G)
    T, L, U = [[] for _ in range(N)], [], [False] * N
    for u in range(N):
        if not U[u]:
            U[u], S = True, [u]
            while S:
                u, done = S[-1], True
                for v in G[u]:
                    T[v].append(u)
                    if not U[v]:
                        U[v], done = True, False
                        S.append(v)
                        break
                if done:
                    S.pop()
                    L.append(u)
    
    # postorder DFS on T to pop root vertices from L and mark SCCs
    C = [None] * N
    while L:
        r = L.pop()
        S = [r]
        if U[r]:
            U[r], C[r] = False, r
        while S:
            u, done = S[-1], True
            for v in T[u]:
                if U[v]:
                    U[v] = done = False
                    S.append(v)
                    C[v] = r
                    break
            if done:
                S.pop()
    
    return C
```

Test example:

```
G = [[1], [0, 2], [0, 3, 4], [4], [5], [6], [4], [6]]

print(kosaraju(G)) # => [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

(Work in progress)
I find the recursive variant pleasant enough to read:
• It picks up the names from the description referred
• The meaning of additional single-letter names isn't hard to guess
• there are comments to what's what

Main gripe:
What can I use `kosaraju(G)` for, does it return something useful?
Have your source code document (non-private) parts:
Use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).

Using [loop-`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), you don't need a `done` flag

```
def kosaraju(G):
    """ For a graph G given as a list of lists of node numbers
        find the strongly connected components.
        Use Kosaraju's algorithm:
        for each unvisited node, traverse and mark visited its out-neighbours,
          then add it to a sequence L
        for each unassigned node taken from L in reverse order,
          assign it to the same new SCC as all nodes reached via in-neighbours
    """
    # postorder DFT on G to transpose the graph and push root vertices to L
    N = len(G)
    T, L, visited = [[] for _ in  range(N)], [], [False] * N
    for u in range(N):
        if visited[u]:
            continue
        visited[u], stack = True, [u]
        while stack:
            u = stack[-1]
            for v in G[u]:
                T[v].append(u)
                if not visited[v]:
                    visited[v] = True
                    stack.append(v)
                    break
            else:
                stack.pop()
                L.append(u)
    # print("L:", L)
    # try and follow en.wikipedia's hint and have
    #  visited indication share storage with the final assignment
    assigned = visited
                         
    # postorder DFT on T to pop root vertices from L and mark SCCs
    assigned = visited   # C = [None] * N
    while L:
        root = L.pop()
        if not visited[root] is True:
            continue
        assigned[root] = root
        stack = [root]
        while stack:
            # print("T[" + stack[-1] + "]: " + T[stack[-1]])
            for v in T[stack[-1]]:
                if visited[v] is True:
                    stack.append(v)
                    assigned[v] = root
                    break
            else:
                stack.pop()
    
    return assigned


if __name__ == '__main__':
    G = [[], [5, 4], [3, 11, 6], [7], [2, 8, 10], [7, 5, 3],
         [8, 11], [9], [2, 8], [3], [1], [9, 6]] 
    print(kosaraju(G))
```